# Put a label on OpenLayers from GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers, geojson

I have a geojson and I want every property to put a label in its middle with a number ..

Here's the function I'm putting on the geojson map:

```
function search(){
    var layer = $('#layer').val();
    console.log(layer);

    proj4.defs('EPSG:31700','+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
    ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "act_geojson.php?layer="+layer,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(response);
            var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
            features.forEach(function(feature){
                feature.setId(undefined);
                feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
                ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
            });
            vectorSource.clear();
            vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
            map.getView().fit(extent);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is geojson:

```
{ "Type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "id" 0 "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates" [[[669,023.843 , 415221.025] [669031.588,415222.415] [669059.365,415154.448] [669064.041,415143.41] [669049.477,415135.059] [668987.876,415095.463] [668934.69,415061.12] [668904.2,415041.659] [668903.285,415044.048 ] [668934.224,415064.815] [668987.091,415097.897] [669048.669,415137.58] [669057.03,415142.935] [669054.159,415149.762] [669049.569,415160.172] [669045.995,415169.095] [669034.656,415197.283] [669031.864,415205.9] [669023.843,415221.025]]]} "CRS": { "type": "EPSG", "properties": { "code": "31700"}} "geometry_name" "wkb_geometry" "properties": { "ogc_fid" 0 "id_teren" "2" "id_cons", "0", "layer", "Green Area", "wkb_geometry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}}, {" type ":" Feature "," id "0" geometry ": {" type ":" Polygon "," coordinates "[[[668906.809,415037.18] [668937.555,415056.882] [668994.661,415093.986] [669051.706,415130.5] [669059.946,415135.898] [669060.159,415135.449] [669051.997,415129.296] [668997.335,415093.406] [668938.441,415054.482] [668908.139,415035.654], [ 668906.809,415037.18]]]} "CRS": { "type": "EPSG", "properties": { "code": "31700"}} "geometry_name" "wkb_geometry", "properties": { " ogc_fid ": 0," id_teren ":" 4 "," id_cons ":" 0 "," layer ":" Green Area "," wkb_geometry ":" 0103000000010000000B0000007F3F359ED569244185EB51B8F4541941C3F5281C136A24410E022B87435519418C976E52856A2441E7FBA9F1D7551 94101D57869F76A2441000000006A5619415AC050E4076B2441800639977F561941AF726851086B2441F0A7C6CB7D561941B4C876FEF76A2441BE9F1A2F65561941B71E85AB8A6A2441C976BE9FD555194182C0CAE1146A2441736891ED395519410C022B47D86924410E2DB29DEE5419417F3F359ED569244185EB51B8F4541941 "}}, {" type ":" Feature "," id "0" geometry ": {" type ":" Polygon "," coordinates "[[[669023.722,415221.059] [669031.864,415205.9] [669034.656,415197.283] [669045.995,415169.095] [669049.569,415160.172] [669025.298,415144.634] [669019.118,415153.567] [669000.213,415207.177] [669023.722,415221.059]]]} "CRS" { "type": "EPSG", "properties": { "code": "31700"}} "geometry_name" "wkb_geometry", "properties": { "ogc_fid" 0 "id_teren" "1" "id_cons": "0", "layer", "Green Area", "wkb_geometry" "01030000000100000009000000E7FBA971BF6A2441FA7E6A3CD45719413F355EBACF6A24419A99999997571941643BDF4FD56A244183C0CA2175571941D8A370FDEB6A244114AE476104571941CFF75323F36A24419CC420B0E0561941BC749398C26A2441C34B3789A2561941FC7E6A3CB66A2441E3A59B44C656194104560E6D906A2441EE7C3FB59 C571941E7FBA971BF6A2441FA7E6A3CD4571941 "}}]}
```

When id_cons is 0 to display id_teren and if id_teren is 0 then id_cons ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you could add text style change in `features.forEach` loop (I used part of [Mike's code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314324/115)):

```
features.forEach(function(feature){
    feature.setId(undefined);
    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:31700', 'EPSG:3857');
    ol.extent.extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
    var myStyle = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: ... // replace ... with fill definition
      stroke: ... // replace ... with stroke definition
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '11px "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", "sans-serif"',
        placement: 'line',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'black'
        })
      })
    });
    var cons = feature.get('id_cons');
    var teren = feature.get('id_teren');
    myStyle.getText().setText(cons == '0' ? teren : cons);
    feature.setStyle(myStyle);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a style function based on to this example https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/vector-layer.html

```
  var style = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#319FD3',
      width: 1
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#fff',
        width: 3
      })
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: features
            }),
            style: function(feature) {
                var cons = feature.get('id_cons');
                var teren = feature.get('id_teren');
                style.getText().setText(cons == '0' ? teren : cons);
                return style;
            }
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View()
  });
```